# Clone with https does not ask for password

Tags: git, github

I am cloning a GIT repo using https on a freshly set up machine (Linux Manjaro). I have not set up anything, but I am **not** getting asked for a password. Furthermore

```
[andreas@Bixente ~]$ git config --system credential.helper 
[andreas@Bixente ~]$ git config --global credential.helper 
[andreas@Bixente ~]$ git config --local credential.helper 
fatal: --local can only be used inside a git repository
```

Any idea why? I am confused.

Comment: A public repository? Try to push — it should fail.

Comment: I am embarrased...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Public repo does not require authentication...